# Can I print large photo on canvas (72''x20''), but also have high resolution (300dpi) and all that in rather small file size?

Tags: print-design, resolution, canvas

Is there a way to have all those 3 things together? Large/high quality/small file size.
Because I need to send this file to an office which have rather old computer system (don't ask) to print it. But they all-ways ask me 300dpi document and this time canvas size is really big, but I'm afraid that they will not be able to even open it. So is there a way to get it smallish? Smaller than 3gb (that's what I have now).
Thanks.
P.S: Photoshop won't even let me save the file in jpg or pdf (I usually use those). Only large formats...

Comment: You really can't control file dimensions, file resolution, *and* file size all at the same time. You can pick two.. but all three is really not possible.

Comment: So no way to save it in a smaller file... Ok, then how low in resolution you would suggest me to go to save space- where's the point where human eye starts  to see the degradation in image quality?

Comment: So, your document would be 21600x6000 pixels. How much is the original photo interpolated to get it to those dimensions? You could just make the document the right print size but let the DPI be what it is without interpolating, and maybe interpolate at the destination computer, if that's an option.

Comment: It's a collage consisting from 3 images. Each of the images is at resolution 72 and dimensions are 60x40 inches. That's what comes out straight from the camera.

Comment: All right, well, what matters now are the amount of pixels, since you want a smaller file size. It's a 3-image collage, so that would mean each image is 7200x6000 pixels, right? That's 43,2 Megapixels per image. Is that really the original image dimensions (the resolution of the camera)?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to save the image as a JPEG (unless your machine has considerably less grunt than the Atom-based netbook with 2GB RAM I just used to save a Ps document of that size as a JPEG), **provided that it's flat, 8-bit and you've selected "Baseline"**. (Baseline optimized and progressive take more memory to process the compression, and I handily ran out of RAM.) Save off the PSD before flattening and changing bit depth, of course. And if you've had Photoshop up and running for a while, you may need to restart in order to reclaim some RAM.

That *should* result in a JPEG file that's under 300MB saved with a quality factor of 12. (Two of the images I saved — all random collages of photos I happened to have on my drive — were under 150MB at 12, the others were just over 200MB to about 250MB.) That's still big, of course, but not 3GB big. Still, you'd have to forego the email option and either FTP or stick it in the cloud for download. (And if it's going to canvas, 12 is probably overkill for file size, but it takes less computation to compress than the smaller options. If 10 gives you a memory error, try 11 or 12.)

Comment: I guess that's where the problem is- I can't save in jpg even with all those things in check-8bit/flat/baseline. Been trying to solve this for 2 days now and can't figure it out. Might be program error...